# Why a validation message is not replaced in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, path-variables

Now I developed REST API using Spring Boot.

I try to validate path parameter and handle a exception with custom message like this.

*FooController.java*

```
@Validated
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FooController {

  private final BarService service;

  @GetMapping(value = "/test/{id}")
  public void invoke(@PathVariable @Digits(integer = 10, fraction = 0, message = "{message}") Long id) {
    service.get(id);
    ...
  }
}
```

*ApiExceptionHandler.java*

```
@RestControllerAdvice
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApiExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
  public ResponseEntity<Object> handleConstraintViolationException(ConstraintViolationException exception) {
    Map<String, String> messages = new HashMap<>();
    for (ConstraintViolation violation : exception.getConstraintViolations()) {
      messages.put("message", violation.getMessage());
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(messages, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
  }
}
```

*ValidationMessages.properties*

```
message={0} must not be more than {integer} digits
```

When I call this API by more than 10 digits (For example, [`GET /test/12345678901`]) to happen 400 error.

My expected response is

```
{
  message : id must not be more than 10 digits
}
```

But, actual response is

```
{
  message : {0} must not be more than 10 digits
}
```

So, my question is "Why a validation message is not replaced".

If this approach is wrong then is there any approach to come get expected response?

Thank you for reading my question.

***Appendix***
Used Spring Boot version is 2.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `${validatedValue}` to get the parameter in the message:

```
message=${validatedValue} must not be more than {integer} digits
```

Please find out more about message interpolation in the docs:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=6.1#section-interpolation-with-message-expressions

Comment: Thank you for quick response and sharing docs link.

I used ${validatedValue}, but the response is following.
`{
  message : 12345678001 must not be more than 10 digits
}`

${validatedValue} is replaced a value(12345678901), not a key(id).
This is not what I want to get.

I will survey more information from docs.

I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: Oh I see. I'm sorry for the misunderstanding. You can write your own MessageInterpolator. There you have access to all the information: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=6.1#section-custom-message-interpolation

Comment: I appreciate your kind. I will try to write own MessageInterpolator. Thank you for your support.